# Looking for a URI match on this regular expression, but it is crashing regex testers

Tags: regex

I'm trying to use this regular expression, but I'm having trouble testing it, because for whatever reason it is crashing the only two regex testers I use.

^([a-zA-Z-]+/?)+$

If I'm not mistaken, that should match any URI that follows this format:

some-uri-string/some-uri-string/some-uri-string

However, I don't want it to match:

some-uri-string/some-uri-string//some-uri-string

Notice the double slash. Essentially, it is category/sub-category/sub-sub-category/page

With any number of sub-categories being allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that, for a non-matching string, your pattern is a pathological case for a backtracking regular expression engine (which is true of those in most scripting languages, like Perl, Python, and anything based on PCRE).

More information:

- http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html
- http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html

You could rewrite it as:

```
^([a-zA-Z-]+/)*[a-zA-Z-]+$
```

Or your RE implementation may have other facilities available to avoid that scenario.

Comment: I made one small change. ^([a-zA-Z-]+/)*[a-zA-Z-]+/?$
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Look up catastrophic backtracking...  You need to define it a little better, or write one that chomps the URI string one part at a time...  This one is recursive, and why it crashes on you...  Or, you may change it from Greedy to lazy..  I didn't actually DEBUG this regex, but that's what I see...

Answer (score 0):

For [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/), you can make the group atomic to avoid catastrophic backtracking. Just add `?>` like this:

```
^(?>[a-zA-Z-]+/?)+$
```

See the [PCRE manual](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt) under "Atomic Grouping and Possessive Quantifiers".

Answer (score 0):

Works using this tester :) Give it a shot - http://ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/java-visual-regex-tester/#!;t=some-uri-string%2Fsome-uri-string%2Fsome-uri-string&r=%5E(%5Ba-zA-Z-%5D%2B%2F%3F)%2B%24&x=